# R regex : find a letter as a word and nothing else

Tags: r, regex

I have this vector of strings :

```
strings <- c("5 EUR 12 EUR", "5 ESCALOPE", "5 E", "87 TOYS")
```

and I just want to GET the element : **5 E**

I tried some regex like this one :

```
grep("[0-9] E", strings, value = TRUE)
```

It returns this : "5 EUR 12 EUR" "5 ESCALOPE"   "5 E"

What I want is a "number and E" and anything else after the E, no spaces, no \n,  \t, ...

If someone has the solution ... thx ^^

Comment: [`grep("^[0-9] E$", strings, value = TRUE)`](https://ideone.com/Bh84WO)

Comment: `stringr::str_extract("[0-9] E")` as you didn't specify if you want '5 ESCALOPE' to return '5 E' or not